# Get the value from inner join

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to retrieve the record using inner join .

In table,

> table1.newfld value is sath1
>   
> table2.domainname value is domnInd/sath1

```
SELECT table1.id,table1.newfld, table2.id
                                    FROM table 1
                                    INNER JOIN table2
                                    ON table1.newfld = table2.domainname;
```

how can I check sath1 value with domnInd/sath1 ? How can i use the split table2.domainname and check with second part. because in table2.domainname after the slash its have the common values.

Answer (score 0):

Use **REVERSE,CHARINDEX,RIGHT**:

**REVERSE :** Gives you given string in reverse order.

**CHARINDEX :** Gives you first index of match character in string.

**RIGHT :** Give a portion of string from the right direction

```
Declare @domainName VARCHAR(50)='domnInd/sath1'

SELECT REVERSE(@domainName)
SELECT CHARINDEX('/',REVERSE(@domainName),0)
SELECT RIGHT(@domainName,CHARINDEX('/',REVERSE(@domainName),0)-1)

SELECT 
    T1.id,
    T1.newfld, 
    T2.id
FROM table1 AS T1
INNER JOIN table2 AS T2 ON T1.newfld = RIGHT(T2.domainname,CHARINDEX('/',REVERSE(T2.domainname),0)-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `CHARINDEX`.

**Query**

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.newfld, t2.id
FROM table1 t1
JOIN table2 t2
ON t1.newfld = RIGHT(t2.domainname, CHARINDEX('/', REVERSE(t2.domainname), 1) -1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
 SELECT table1.id,table1.newfld, table2.id
           FROM table 1
           INNER JOIN table2
           ON table1.newfld = substring(table2.domainname,CHARINDEX('/',table2.domainname)+1,len(table2.domainname) - 1);
```

Comment: The following error came : Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.

Comment: do you have any null in that field?

Comment: are you sure  you have `/` in all values?

Comment: can you recheck it? becoz i have updated once after posted.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to check if `table1.newfld` is present in `table2.domainname`,you can do it using `LIKE`

```
SELECT table1.id,table1.newfld, table2.id
FROM table 1
INNER JOIN table2
ON table2.domainname like '%' + table1.newfld + '%';
```

This will check `table2.domainname` and if `table1.newfld` is present anywhere it will select that record.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

`PARSENAME` is designed specifically to parse an sql object name.

```
 SELECT table1.id,table1.newfld, table2.id
               FROM table 1
               INNER JOIN table2
               ON table1.newfld =PARSENAME(REPLACE(t2.domainname,'/','.'), 1)
```

For ref: [More description of parse name](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188006.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Using STUFF:

```
SELECT table1.id,table1.newfld, table2.id
    FROM table 1
    INNER JOIN table2
    ON table1.newfld = STUFF(table2.domainname, 1, CHARINDEX('/',table2.domainname), '')
```